# How to read/copy files from unix box to windows using Java SSH

Tags: java, windows, unix

Are there any simple open source java class to read/copy files from unix box to windows using Java SSH

Comment: Yes.JSCH is the best implementation of the Java SSH with less code and not lot of dependencies.try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation of the SSH protocol written in pure Java: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/